# 12154 error when using PL/SQL Developer

Tags: oracle, oracle-10g, plsql

I have installed a few versions of Oracle on my machine. I have tried 64 bit and 32 bit versions. I have installed 11G. I need Oracle 10G 32 bit.

Using the following guide I removed all versions of Oracle from my PC:

```
Uninstall all Oracle components using the Oracle Universal Installer (OUI).
Delete the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/SOFTWARE/ORACLE key which contains registry entries for all Oracle products by using regedit.
Delete any references to Oracle services/components in the following registry location: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/SYSTEM/CurrentControlSet/Services/. Looks for key entries that starts with “Ora” which are obviously related to Oracle.
Reboot the workstation.
Delete the ORACLE_BASE directory. (i.e C:\Oracle)
Delete the C:\Program Files\Oracle directory.
Empty the temp directory.
Empty the recycle bin.
```

http://www.mydigitallife.info/manual-and-clean-uninstall-oracle-for-windows/

I then installed Oracle 10G 32bit.

When I go to connect in PL/SQL Developer I get:

ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified. (https://i.stack.imgur.com/UGpwD.png)

I have set up my *Oracle Home* and added a value for *tns_admin*. My TNSNAMES.ORA file is in the directory referenced by *tns_admin*.

I think my Oracle is picking up the TNSNAMES.ORA file as the drop-down list for Database in populated in PL/SQL Developer.

The only options I see at the moment are:

1. Uninstall and try again
2. Re-install Windows to make sure the settings are gone.

Any help you could give would be appreciated.

Comment: Your question isn't completely clear. You've installed the Oracle 10G client, right? Put your tnsnames.ora in the `%ORACLE_HOME%\network\admin` directory.

Comment: @Phil yep the TNSNAMES.ORA file can be found there C:\oracle\product\10.2.0\client_1\NETWORK\ADMIN

Comment: open a cmd prompt and try `tnsping MYDBNAME`. You might have to add the Oracle bin path to the `%PATH%`

Comment: @Phil I get an OK response when I run that. No error.

Comment: Must be a PL/SQL Developer problem then. I don't use it, so can't help you I'm afraid

Comment: are there valid entries in your tnsnames.ora file? open a cmd window and type "tnsping <db_name>" and show the results?